# Calling readStream.destroy() on a node js read stream doesn't stop the reading

Tags: javascript, node.js

I hope you are all doing well.

I am facing an issue with streams in Node Js and I would like to solicit your help:

I am reading a file with: const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./veryBigFile');

and I pipe the output to a POST request like this:

readStream.pipe(post_req);

However, I would like to stop the reading from the file after a certain timeout , and also to stop the POST request.

I tried both readStream.close() and readStream.destroy() but they don't work (I attached an 'end' listener to readStream, and it doesn't get triggered after the timeout).

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'd also like to know!

Comment: @KirillGroshkov I just answered my own question below. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment kirill Groshkov, I decided to take a look again at my code and I understood how to make it work !

After a destroy event is tirggered (with readStream.destroy()), it is an 'error' event that is emitted, not an 'end' event which I was listening to.

So I still had to use readStream.destroy('YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE') to stop reading from the file after timeout.

Then I listened to this custom error with:

```
        readStream.on('error', e => {
        if (e === 'YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE') {
            post_req.abort(); //To cancel request
            // etc.
        } else {
            reject(`An error occured while uploading data: ${e}`);
        }
    });
```